# Problema com printf e scanf - Meu codigo não imprime as informações corretas

Tags: c, scanf, printf

Estou com esse código aqui que não está lendo corretamente os caracteres na hora de imprimir os dados preenchidos pelo usuário na tela.
Podem me ajudar??

//Questão 1) Faça um algoritmo que leia o nome, rg, idade, sexo, endereço, telefone e celular de um usuário. 
//Imprima os dados do usuário na tela. (Valor 0,1 ponto)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(){

     char nome [50], sexo [50], end [50]; 
     int rg, idade, telefone, celular;

     printf("Nome: ");     scanf("%s",nome);
     printf("RG: ");       scanf("%d",&rg);
     printf("Idade: ");    scanf("%d",&idade);
     printf("Sexo: ");     scanf("%s",sexo);
     printf("Telefone: "); scanf("%d",&telefone);
     printf("Celular: ");  scanf("%d",&celular);
     printf("Endereco: "); scanf("%s",end);

     printf("\nNome:%s",nome);
     printf("\nRG:%d",&rg);
     printf("\nIdade:%d",&idade);
     printf("\nsexo:%s",sexo);
     printf("\nTelefone:%s",&telefone);
     printf("\nCelular:%d",&celular);
     printf("\nEndereco:%s",end);
```

Comment: Esse código é da linguagem `C`, e não `C#`.

Comment: Você usa o padrão `&variável` na função `scanf`, porque ela precisa alterar o valor da variável, mas na função `printf` você usa somente `variavel`, e não `&variavel`.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá: no RG, na idade, no telefone e no celular você está usando o & antes da variável (na hora de imprimir). Segue o código corrigido:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
 char nome [50], sexo [50], end [50];
 int rg, idade, telefone, celular;

 printf("Nome: ");
 scanf("%s",nome);
 printf("RG: ");
 scanf("%d",&rg);
 printf("Idade: ");
 scanf("%d",&idade);
 printf("Sexo: ");
 scanf("%s",sexo);
 printf("Telefone: ");
 scanf("%d",&telefone);
 printf("Celular: ");
 scanf("%d",&celular);
 printf("Endereco: ");
 scanf("%s",end);

 printf("\nNome:%s",nome);
 printf("\nRG:%d", rg);
 printf("\nIdade:%d", idade);
 printf("\nsexo:%s", sexo);
 printf("\nTelefone:%d", telefone);
 printf("\nCelular:%d", celular);
 printf("\nEndereco:%s\n",end);
}
```